# How to solucionate the error to Upgrade project to Django 4.2.3

Tags: python, django, django-4.0

I have a Django project in the 3.1.2 version. However, I need upgrade it to a new version, to 4.2.3.

I´m having the following message when I upgrade the project. How to solucionate this?

```
"django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'core'. Check that 'apps.core.apps.CoreConfig.name' is correct.
"
```

In the 3.1.2 version, this works well.

Follow the structure of the folders of the project:

```
|.quality
  |.. apps   
     |... core
     |... changelog
  |.. quality
      |... init.py 
      |... asgi.py 
      |... settings.py 
      |... urls.py 
      |... wsgi.py 
  |.. static 
  |.. templates 
  |.. venv
```

Follow the Installed_apps in the settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrapform',
    'apps.core',
    'apps.changelog',   
]
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there!

Make sure to place an `__init__.py` file within your `apps` directory

An example of the folder structure would be:

```bash
apps
├── __init__.py
└── core
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py

3 directories, 8 files
```

Additionally, configure your `apps/core/apps.py` file as follows:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'apps.core'
```